# Proving De Morgan's law with the minus sign

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I know how to prove De Morgan's Law in this form: $A\cap (B\cup C)^{c}$, what I'm trying to do for practice is prove it in the slightly different notation: $A- (B\cup C)$

I get everything except I end up with a union instead of intersection:

$$A-(B\cup C) \\= A-(A\cap(B\cup C)) \\= A- ((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)) \\= (A- (A\cap B)) \cup (A-(A\cap C)) \\= (A-B) \cup (A-C)$$

I know this last line is supposed to be $(A-B) \cap (A-C)$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go wrong in the 4th line:

$$ A- ((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)) \\\neq (A- (A\cap B)) \cup (A-(A\cap C))$$

After all, $A - (X \cup Y)$ is $(A - X) \cap (A - Y)$ !

Comment: so then it should read $$(A-(A\cap B)) \cap (A-(A\cap C))$$. I don't think I've ever seen that rule being applied before, then again I'm not comfortable with the minus sign form of complements yet

Comment: That's right. I find it easier to manipulate if I visualise what it means.

Answer (score 1):

$A-(B\cup C)=A\cap(\overline{B\cup C})\stackrel{\text{DM}}=A\cap (\overline{B}\cap\overline{C})$

$=(A\cap \overline{B})\cap(A\cap \overline{C})=(A-B)\cap(A-C)$

DM-DeMorgan.

Comment: I understand that version of the proof. I.e using the $\cap$ instead of a " - " sign. It is the version where I would have to carry the minus sign throughout that I am curious about.